# Simple question about special matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Consider $A \in O(n)$, that's to say $A \in M_n(\mathbb R)$ st $AA_T=I$, and assume that $\det A=-1$.
How can we demonstrate that there exists $A' \in SO(n)$, that's to say $A'\in O(n)$ and $\det A'=1$ and there exists $J$ which represents a reflection with respect to an hyperplane st $A'J=A$?

Comment: Yes, I write it down badly. I meant that we consider a Matrix in O(n) with det=-1, i will edit. Thank you

Comment: @Surb Isn't the determinant of $-A$ equal to $(-1)^n\det(A)$ so that the example only works in odd dimension?

Comment: @Nightgap: indeed, you right (I had in mind $n=2$) but you right, my example is not good :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since reflections satisfy $J^2=I$, we can restate the desired result as $A^\prime=AJ$. Then $A^\prime A^{\prime T}=AJJ^TA^T$. If $J$ is a self-transpose reflection, $A^\prime A^{\prime T}=I$. So we just need to choose a self-transpose reflection of determinant $-1$. The obvious choice is for $J$ to be diagonal, with one eigenvalue $-1$ while the others are $1$.